# How would you say "denier" in Latin?

Tags: word-request

An example of deniers are The Mad Revisionists. They are conspiracy theorists who think the Moon doesn't exist. In other words, they are Moon deniers. How would you say "Moon denier" in Latin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lūnae [negātor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negator#Latin) or Lūnae negātiōnista.

However [-ista](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ista#Latin) suffix is more Greek.

(An English synonym of denialism is negationism.)

Comment: Does "*negator*" have the same connotations as "*denier*" does in English?

Comment: I think that it is rather modern political concept. Regardless of whether such connotations existed in antiquity, I think that you could add them in Neo-Latin usage...

Comment: I'd use *negationista*, because that's the same as our Portuguese Negacionista

Comment: @Arfrever Seriously? It's a modern concept? There were no deniers in Ancient Rome?

Comment: I'd *not* use *negationista* because it is a barbarism of the worst order. (Specifically a gallicism, I believe – *négationniste* – and that word usually refers to holocaust deniers.)

Answer (score 6):

I would write something like: *qui negat lunam esse*.

I would avoid *lunae negator* for a number of reasons:

- *negator* is not classically attested. Nor was it really needed, when it was just as well possible to say *negans* or *qui negat*.
- Admittedly, *negator* is attested in Tertullian (2nd/3rd century), close enough. But he uses *negare* in the religious sense, to reject Christ or God, and this does not mean to deny the existence (e.g. Luc 12, 9: *qui autem negaverit me coram hominibus, negabitur coram angelis Dei* – this does not mean Jesus is an apostasy denier).

And that's really the rub: as far as I can see, you can *negare* a *crimen*, or otherwise all kinds of allegation, or you can *negare* a debt (renege on), or a person, but I posit that you cannot *negare* a thing, such as the moon. Therefore you cannot say *qui lunam negat*, and therefore also not simply *lunae negator*.

Comment: This is generally in line with words like ἄθεος. I think "refuse" might even be a better translation, except that *negare* can mean "to deny [the fact that]", so I could see *negator* being a potential possibility. However, your formulation is much more in line with how the Romans actually spoke, so it gets my vote for best answer.